# the installer encountered errors before apple mobile device support could be configured

Tags: itunes, windows

I'm having issues with installing Apple mobile device support. Every time I try to install Apple mobile device support I get this annoying message:

the installer encountered errors before apple mobile device support could be configured

I have tried these two ideas with no luck.

Had this issue, and none of the solutions above worked, here is what I did to fix the issue, Install iTunes like you normally would, admin rights etc.

When you get the error message

> iTunes errors occurred during installation before iTunes could be configured" do not click finish, leave that folder up, no navigate to your appdata directory such as example `C:\Users\Your Username\appdata\local\temp`, inside there look for a file called iTunes64Setup.log or iTunes32Setup1850.log, open that up and scroll down, look for these key things as in example,

```
"Executing: "C:\windows\system32\msiexec.exe" /i C:\Users\Crusisxx\AppData\Local\Temp\IXP593.TMP\iTunes64.msi" INSTALL_SUPPORT_PACKAGES=1"
```

so I would navigate inside the folder in my temp called "IXP593.TMP, there you will find all the installation packages, copy all of those files and paste either on your desktop or a new folder ect, once done you can now click finish on the failed itunes installer, now whether or not where ever you decided to place your files you copied from that temp folder you will want to run Itunes64.msi or Itunes.msi ect, and run the installer, you should now have successfully of installed Itunes.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5418367?tstart=0

I got it. I just first uninstalled iTunes then this:

1. Open up the Command Prompt as an Administrator (Go to All Programs > Accessories and Right Click on Command Prompt and then choose Run as administrator)
2. Type `cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64`
3. Type `regsvr32 vbscript.dll` (This registers VB Script with your computer.)
4. Now install iTunes as you normally would by double clicking on the install program and wait for iTunes to finish installing.
5. Type `regsvr32 /u vbscript.dll` (This unregisters VB Script with your computer.)

https://discussions.apple.com/message/10790766#10790766

What else can I do and why is it not working?